# Solve $\sec (\theta)=\csc (4\theta)$ for $0^{\circ } \leq \theta \leq 90^{\circ}$

Tags: trigonometry

Solve $\sec (\theta)=\csc (4\theta)$ for $0^{\circ } \leq \theta \leq 90^{\circ}$

My Attempt:
$$\sec (\theta)=\csc (4\theta )$$
$$\cos (\theta)= \sin (4\theta) $$
$$\cos (\theta)= \cos (90 - 4\theta)$$
This gives only one value of $\theta$ i.e $18^{\circ }$. But there are other two values of $\theta $ i.e $30$ and $90$. How to get all the values?

Comment: Since cos a even function, it follows that $\cos \theta = \cos (90^{\circ}-4\theta) $ implies  $\theta=90^{\circ}-4\theta$ or  $-\theta=90^{\circ}-4\theta$.

Answer (score 1):

$\cos(\theta)=\cos(\eta)$ if and only if $\theta=\eta+2 \pi n$ for some integer $n$ or $\theta=-\eta + 2 \pi n$ for some integer $n$*. In the former case the two angles represent the same point on the circle; in the latter case the two angles represent two points on the circle that are reflections of one another through the $x$ axis.

So in your question, $\theta=\pi/2 - 4 \theta + 2\pi n$ or $\theta=-\pi/2+4\theta + 2 \pi n$, and now you can solve for $\theta$. Then you can restrict attention to one copy of the circle (by imposing suitable restrictions on $n$) if you wish.

* I write in radians, you can replace $2\pi$ with $360$ for degrees.

Answer (score 0):

HINT.-You have $\cos(\theta)=\sin(4\theta)=2\sin(2\theta)\cos(\theta)=\sqrt{\dfrac{1+\cos(2\theta)}{2}}$.

Putting $X=\cos(2\theta)$ you get the equation $8X^4-8X^2+X+1=0$. 
But $$8X^4-8X^2+X+1=(4X^2-2X-1)(2X-1)(X+1)$$

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the equation $\cos (\theta)- \cos (90 - 4\theta)=0$ as

$$2\sin\frac{90-3\theta}2\sin\frac{90-5\theta}2=0$$

which leads to $\frac{90-3\theta}2 = \pi n$ and $\frac{90-5\theta}2 = \pi n$, or

$$\theta = \frac{90-\pi n}3=30,\> 90,\>\>\>\>\>
\theta = \frac{90-\pi n}5=18$$
where $\theta=90$ is excluded because $\csc(4\cdot90) $ is undefined.